# using codeigniter data is not inserting into the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

i have tried for a solution on web , i couldn't find any answer still, i followed the below code ., still my data is not going into the database .,

this is my controller pages.php

```
  <?php
  class pages extends CI_Controller {

  function view($page = 'index') {
    $this->load->view('pages/index');
  }

  function insert_data(){
    $data = array(
        'name' =>  $this->input->post('name'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'message' => $this->input->post('message')
    );
    $this->load->model('contact_model');
    $this->contact_model->insert_entry($data);
    echo json_encode($data);
 }

 }

 ?>
```

this is my view pages/index.php

```
 <form id="submit">

 name <input  type="text" id="name" >    

 email<input type="email" id="email">


 message<textarea id="message"></textarea>              

 <button type="button"  id="submit1">Send</button>
  <a id="ack"></a>         
   </form>
```

this is my model contact_model.php

```
   <?php

    class contact_model extends CI_Model {
   function insert_entry($data) {
    $this->db->insert('contactus', $data);
   }

   }
   ?>
```

this is my js file custom.js

```
     $("#submit1").on('click',function(){
      $.ajax({
     url: "<?php echo site_url('pages/insert_data');?>",
     type: 'POST',
     data: {"name": $("#name").val(), "email": $("#email").val(), "message":  
    $("#message").val()},
         success: function(data) {
         $("#ack").html(data); 
      }
      });
     });
```

Comment: can you take the posted date in your controller. Before calling model function for insert check the posted data.

Comment: Try to print query using $this->db->last_query(); and see if all ok.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter you need to specify the database is available in the model when loading like this...

```
$this->load->model('MyModel','',true);
```

See the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#conn) for details.

Alternatively you can manually load and connect to the database in your model using

```
$this->load->database();
```

Before running any queries

Also this

```
url: "<?php echo site_url('pages/insert_data');?>",
```

Will fail in a .js file. You can either take the javascript and put it into index.php or define a javascript variable before including the .js file and use that variable for the url ie...

```
//index.php
<script>var sendUrl = "<?php echo site_url('pages/insert_data');?>"</script>
<script src="path/to/js/custom.js"></script>
```

and change the offending line to

```
//custom.js
url: sendUrl,
```

Comment: i am new to codeigniter i did not understand what you said

Comment: Change the line `$this->load->model('contact_model');` to `$this->load->model('contact_model','',true);` in your `pages.php` controller and try again.

Comment: better than before after i tried i got this error POST http://localhost/ci/%3C?php%20echo%20site_url(%27pages/insert_data%27);?%3E 404 (Not Found)

Comment: take the javascript out of the javascript file and put it into the index.php file. You can't echo php in a `.js` file.

Comment: Or see my updated answer for an alternative solution.

Comment: var sendUrl = "<?php echo site_url('pages/insert_data');?>" where should I add this in index.php shud i do it like this <script>var sendUrl = "<?php echo site_url('pages/insert_data');?>"</script>

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the database connection is available and the user used to establish the connection have the write permission. The below code may help you.

[codeigniter sample db application](http://sanjaykumarns.blogspot.in/p/codeigniter-sample-application.html)

Answer (score 0):

try like this in model file

```
<?php

    class contact_model extends CI_Model {
     * Calls parent constructor
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

   function insert_entry($data) {
    $this->db->insert('contactus', $data);
   }

   }
   ?>
```